# R: row-wise dplyr::mutate using function that takes a data frame row and returns an integer

Tags: r, row, dplyr

I am trying to use pipe mutate statement using a custom function. I looked a this somewhat similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001070/r-use-dplyrmutate-dplyrtransmute-with-a-function-which-acts-on-an-entire-ro) but in vain.
Say I have a data frame like this (where `blob` is some variable not related to the specific task but is part of the entire data) :

```
df <- 
  data.frame(exclude=c('B','B','D'), 
             B=c(1,0,0), 
             C=c(3,4,9), 
             D=c(1,1,0), 
             blob=c('fd', 'fs', 'sa'), 
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I have a function that uses the variable names so select some based on the value in the `exclude` column and e.g. calculates a sum on the variables not specified in `exclude` (which is always a single character).

```
FUN <- function(df){
  sum(df[c('B', 'C', 'D')] [!names(df[c('B', 'C', 'D')]) %in% df['exclude']] )
}
```

When I gives a single row (row 1) to `FUN` I get the the expected sum of `C` and `D` (those not mentioned by `exclude`), namely 4:

```
FUN(df[1,])
```

How do I do similarly in a pipe with mutate (adding the result to a variable `s`). These two tries do not work:

```
df %>% mutate(s=FUN(.))
df %>% group_by(1:n()) %>% mutate(s=FUN(.))
```

**UPDATE**
This also do not work as intended:

```
df %>% rowwise(.) %>% mutate(s=FUN(.))
```

This works of cause but is not within dplyr's mutate (and pipes):

```
df$s <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) FUN(df[x,]))
```

Comment: Could you give an example? This does not work: `df %>% rowwise(.) %>% mutate(s=FUN(.))`. The answer from @konvas appears somewhat clumpsy (see my comment to @konvas's suggestion)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.You can do `df %>% rowwise(.) %>% mutate(s=FUN(data.frame(exclude = exclude, B = B, C = C, D = D)))`, or `df %>% rowwise() %>% nest(exclude:D) %>% mutate(s = map_dbl(data, FUN)) %>% unnest()`. The issue is that `dplyr` does not naturally operate on sub data.frames, but on columns (i.e. vectors). So some additional trickery will be necessary.

Comment: This is more what I am after ! (For the record:  it is `tidyr::nest()` and `purrr::map_dbl()` ).

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use `dplyr` you can do so using `rowwise` and your function `FUN`.

```
df %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    do({
        result = as_data_frame(.)
        result$s = FUN(result)
        result
    })
```

The same can be achieved using `group_by` instead of `rowwise` (like you already tried) but with `do` instead of `mutate`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(1:n()) %>% 
    do({
        result = as_data_frame(.)
        result$s = FUN(result)
        result
    })
```

The reason `mutate` doesn't work in this case, is that you are passing the whole tibble to it, so it's like calling `FUN(df)`.

A much more efficient way of doing the same thing though is to just make a matrix of columns to be included and then use `rowSums`.

```
cols <- c('B', 'C', 'D')
include_mat <- outer(function(x, y) x != y, X = df$exclude, Y = cols)
# or outer(`!=`, X = df$exclude, Y = cols) if it's more readable to you
df$s <- rowSums(df[cols] * include_mat)
```

Comment: Yes thanks, but my example above (sum) was just a toy example. My aim is to understand how to use a(ny) custom function with dplyr::mutate within the dplyr pipe (`%>%`). The suggestion within a do() statement seems very (as you say) inefficient and statefull - there much be a simpler way. I could also have done much more efficient (but then this is not with dplyr mutate and pipes): `df$s <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) FUN(df[x,]))` .

Answer (score 12):

### `purrr` approach

We can use a combination of `nest` and `map_dbl` for this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  nest(-blob) %>% 
  mutate(s = map_dbl(data, FUN)) %>% 
  unnest
```

Let's break that down a little bit.  First, `rowwise` allows us to apply each subsequent function to support arbitrary complex operations that need to be applied to each row.

Next, `nest` will create a new column that is a list of our data to be fed into `FUN` (the beauty of tibbles vs data.frames!).  Since we are applying this `rowwise`, each row contains a single-row tibble of `exclude:D`.

Finally, we use `map_dbl` to map our `FUN` to each of these tibbles.  `map_dbl` is used over the family of other `map_*` functions since our intended output is numeric (i.e. double).

`unnest` returns our tibble into the more standard structure.

### `purrrlyr` approach

While `purrrlyr` may not be as 'popular' as its parents `dplyr` and `purrr`, its `by_row` function has some utility here.

In your above example, we would use your data frame `df` and user-defined function `FUN` in the following way:

```
df %>% 
  by_row(..f = FUN, .to = "s", .collate = "cols")
```

That's it! Giving you:

```
# tibble [3 x 6]
  exclude     B     C     D  blob     s
    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1       B     1     3     1    fd     4
2       B     0     4     1    fs     5
3       D     0     9     0    sa     9
```

Admittedly, the syntax is a little strange, but here's how it breaks down:

- `..f` = the function to apply to each row
- `.to` = the name of the output column, in this case `s`
- `.collate` = the way the results should be collated, by list, row, or column.  Since `FUN` only has a single output, we would be fine to use either `"cols"` or `"rows"`

See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrrlyr/versions/0.0.2/topics/by_row) for more information on using `purrrlyr`...

---

### Performance

Forewarning, while I like the functionality of `by_row`, it's not always the best approach for performance!  `purrr` is more intuitive, but also at a rather large speed loss.  See the following `microbenchmark` test:

```
library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  purrr.test = df %>% rowwise %>% nest(-blob) %>% 
    mutate(s = map_dbl(data, FUN)) %>% unnest,
  purrrlyr.test = df %>% by_row(..f = FUN, .to = "s", .collate = "cols"),
  rowwise.test = df %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    do({
      result = as_tibble(.)
      result$s = FUN(result)
      result
    }),
  group_by.test = df %>% 
    group_by(1:n()) %>% 
    do({
      result = as_tibble(.)
      result$s = FUN(result)
      result
    }),
  sapply.test = {df$s <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) FUN(df[x,]))}, 
  times = 1000
)
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

You can see that the `purrrlyr` approach is faster than the approach of using a combination of `do` with `rowwise` or `group_by(1:n())` (see @konvas answer), and rather on par with the `sapply` approach.  However, the package is admittedly not the most intuitive.  The standard `purrr` approach seems to be the slowest, but also perhaps easier to work with.  Different user-defined functions may change the speed order.