# R: call function with data.frame column names as arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a `data.frame` with numerical data and a function that takes the column names as arguments. How do I call the function with those columns as arguments? Something like python's unpacking.

The reason I can't just hard-code it is that the column names, the number of columns, and the function itself changes - but always so that the column names match the function arguments.

Here is a simple version of the problem.

```
func = function(a, b, c) a * b^2 + c
df = data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))
df %>%
    mutate(result = func(.))  # what to do here that doesn't involve "a", "b", "c"?
```

I have tried a [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851170/1297830) involving `rowwise()` but it is awfully slow. `func` can do vectorized computation.

My current solution is quite ugly:

```
call_str = paste0("func(", paste0(colnames(df), " = df$", colnames(df), collapse=","), ")")
result = eval(parse(text = call_str))
```

In this example, `call_str` is

```
"func(a = df$a, b = df$b, c = df$c)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
df %>% mutate(result = do.call("func", .))
```

or `invoke` which is a similar function in purrr:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% mutate(result = invoke("func", .))
```

or `lift` which acts on the function itself producing a new function:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% mutate(result = lift(func)(.))
```